# WebUSB and groupId identification

Tags: web-audio-api, webusb

I am trying to find a way to identify if WebUSB is a part of the same multifunctional device (i.e. printer). As an example of that I can imagine the device that consist of audio and WebUSB functionality. For audio part I can use following API:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
```

which returns **deviceId** and **groupId**. However, in case of the WebUSB there is no such group identifier that can be used fr matching both devices. The only thing that can be done is to request for device:

```
var device = navigator.usb.requestDevices({filters:[]})
```

and check for the serial number - but it doesn't help matching device retrieved by two APIs.
I found an old discussion regarding the unique identifier for device here:
https://github.com/w3ctag/design-reviews/issues/64

However, it doesn't look there was any conclusion for that. Is there any mechanism that would allow verify if WebUSB and WebAudio (or other API) belongs to the same hardware?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really interesting question which we (in the Chromium project) haven't had the opportunity to fully explore. Ideally you would be able to group the interfaces returned by various APIs by device. Unfortunately the implementations of these APIs in the browser are almost entirely unaware of each other and rely on different operating system APIs that also may not be aware of each other. To make a long story short, there will be a lot of work necessary to build up this kind of grouping reliably.

That said, both the WebUSB and WebAudio APIs provide access to some device properties and so a loose correlation should be possible based on things like device name.

Comment: For one device connected it is a simple task - but I can imagine a situation when multiple devices of the same type are being connected to the host. In that case the only unique identifier would be a serial number. While serial number is easily achievable via WebUSB it is not being accessible from other APIs (like WebAudio). What I noticed is that WebAudio is using GUID for deviceId creation - so it seems it is more relying on information provided by OS than hardware itself (which in case of audio has completely sense - not all audio devices have serial number).